# Dependency table for spring boot 2.4.3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a difficulty defining what dependencies versions are compatible with each other.

In my case i have this

[image]

I don't know for the spring boot 2.4.3 what versions of the dependencies below go with it or the cloud version to 2020.0.1.

How can i fix this for example i want to migrate the spring boot and spring cloud to its latest versions.

Comment: Here's one hint https://start.spring.io/actuator/info. Also hystrix is not part of spring cloud as of 2020.0 (version 3.x of its modules). This was announced in Dec 2019 https://spring.io/blog/2019/12/23/spring-cloud-roadmap-and-hoxton-and-greenwich-maintenance-and-eol-announcements

Comment: "spring-cloud-services":{"2.2.6.RELEASE":"Spring Boot >=2.2.0.RELEASE and <2.3.0.RELEASE","2.3.0.RELEASE":"Spring Boot >=2.3.0.RELEASE and <2.4.0-M1"} for me the spring boot is >2.4.x 2.4.3 so there is no version covering this? and what does it mean if hystrix isnt included when it comes to the dependencies? @spencergibb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a good rule of thumb to not define the versions yourself but use BOMs and let them define the versions for you:

- [spring-boot-dependencies](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.4.3/pom)
- [spring-cloud-dependencies](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/2020.0.1/pom)

In order to find out which BOMs to use, you can use [this compatibility matrix](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud#adding-spring-cloud-to-an-existing-spring-boot-application) or the endpoint that @spencergibb mentioned: https://start.spring.io/actuator/info.

If you want to use a Spring Project that is not in the BOM, most probably that Spring Project is not supported (e.g.: Netflix libraries by latest Spring Cloud as @spencergibb mentioned).

**Update:** here's a Gradle example but you can generate a whole project using [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.4.3.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=15&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=cloud-resilience4j,web):

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.3'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
  id 'java'
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
dependencyManagement {
  imports {
    mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.1'
  }
}
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-circuitbreaker-resilience4j'
}
```

Comment: If i understood well, i just defined the main dependencies and added versionning for dependencies that are not included already. springbootVersion=2.4.3
springCloudVersion=2020.0.1
springCloudStarterNetflixHystrixVersion=2.2.7.RELEASE
springCloudServicesStarterConfigClientVersion=3.2.1.RELEASE   and mavenBom "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springbootVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}" but still getting application run failed.

Comment: No, you should not define versions at all (except the BOMs), the BOMs will define the versions for you (see my edited answer). Check the docs of [spring-cloud-circuitbreaker](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-circuitbreaker/docs/current/reference/html/)
or generate a project using [spring initializer](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.4.3.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=15&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=cloud-resilience4j,web)

Answer (score 1):

It might be because there are collisions between dependencies included from the start and your explicitly defined dependencies. For example, take this dependency: **spring-cloud-contract**

Your version:  **2.1.5**

2020.0.1 Spring cloud's supported version: **3.0.1** (check this [link](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-dependencies/2020.0.1/pom) mentioned by @Jonatan)

Try to exclude built-in dependencies that you have explicitly defined. For Maven it would be:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2020.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-verifier</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

But **that might not** work because not all libraries are backward compatible. I would suggest using default libraries provided by spring cloud and remove explicit dependencies.